FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ort::Exception'
  what():  /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/session/provider_bridge_ort.cc:1193 onnxruntime::Provider& onnxruntime::ProviderLibrary::Get() [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Failed to load library libonnxruntime_providers_cuda.so with error: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Signal: SIGABRT (Aborted)

in CMakeLists.txt, I have add this lib abs path and I make sure this lib path exist
file(GLOB cuda_libs /usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64/*.so*)
file(GLOB cudnn_libs /home/roroco/Downloads/cpp-lib/cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.9.0.131_cuda11-archive/lib/*.so.*)
file(GLOB onnx_libs /home/roroco/Downloads/cpp-lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-gpu-1.16.3/lib/*.so.*)
file(GLOB cv_libs /home/roroco/Downloads/cpp-lib/opencv-4.9.0/dist/lib/*.so.*)
set(libs
        ${cuda_libs}
        ${cudnn_libs}
        ${onnx_libs}
        ${cv_libs}
        /home/roroco/Downloads/cpp-lib/cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.9.0.131_cuda11-archive/lib/libcudnn.so.8
)
message("libs:${libs}")
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES libs)

# Link the libraries to your executable
target_link_libraries(inference ${libs})

How to fix it

In my case, my /usr/local have no cudnn libs, I should add cudnn lib dir to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/roroco/Downloads/cpp-lib/cudnn-linux-x86_64-8.9.0.131_cuda11-archive/lib cpp_cmd

way 1: set LD_LIBRARY_PATH forever:
in ~/.bashr, ad export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:path/to/cudnn/lib/dir
way 2: set LD_LIBRARY_PATH tmply:
In clion debug conf, I can set env var

